# Error transporting binary data over ssh/telnet (even shell) in expect script

Tags: linux, binary, expect, telnet

It seems like no one is maintaining [this repo](https://github.com/aeruder/expect/issues/1) and [this repo](https://sourceforge.net/p/expect/feature-requests/) any more.

Assuming I'd like to fetch data from remote with `user/password` auth automating in `expect` script, like the following:
*ps: I use `sh` to refer ssh/telnet connection*

```sh
$ expect -v
expect vesion 5.45.4
$ cat expect.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho sh -c ./download.sh
interact
$ cat download.sh
#!/bin/sh

sh -c 'cat /bin/ls' # cat a binary file
$ ./expect.sh > a.out
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version1 (SYSV), too many program (2304)
```

As the last command said, captured command `ls` (i.e. a.out) has broken locally. And you can find if you actually run the script, the two files are different in bytesize (let alone checksum).

I though it might be related to traslation and encoding issue, so I change the `expect.sh` script to this and it still not working

```sh
$ cat expect.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho sh -c ./download.sh
fconfigure $spawn_id -translation binary -encoding binary
fconfigure stdin -translation binary -encoding binary
fconfigure stdout -translation binary -encoding binary
interact
```

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Usually dumping a binary file to tty would cause unexpected results. You can just try `cat /bin/ls` in an interactive shell and see what would happen. A tty is not a pass-through pipe. It does not output exactly what is sent to it.

See this simple example:

```
[STEP 101] # printf '\n'

[STEP 102] # printf '\n' | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
[STEP 103] #
[STEP 104] # expect -c 'spawn -noecho printf \n; expect eof'

[STEP 105] # expect -c 'spawn -noecho printf \n; expect eof' | hexdump -C
00000000  0d 0a                                             |..|
00000002
[STEP 106] #
[STEP 107] # expect -d -c 'spawn -noecho printf \n; expect eof'
expect version 5.45.4
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {57875}

expect: read eof
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n"
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = -c  argv[3] = spawn -noecho printf \n; expect eof
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
[STEP 108] #
```

As you can see, `\n` is converted to `\r\n` when outputted to the tty.

Comment: Indeed, translation of `\r\n` is done by expect. This is not a very big deal for text file since it doesn't chang too much thing. But modification of binary data is more severe and annoying.

Comment: it's not Expect who converts `\n` to `\r\n`. it's the tty who does this. Expect allocates a pty and run the spawned process on the pty.

Comment: Is it possible to disable tty/pty allocation in expect?

Comment: not quite sure. but if you dont need a pty then you dont have to use Exepct.

Answer (score 0):

You should have more success if you set the tty to raw mode first. In `expect` this is done by setting global variable `stty_init` to the sort of string values you would give the `stty` command. For example,

```tcl
set stty_init raw
log_user 0
spawn ssh user@host "cat /bin/ls; sleep 1"
expect assword: {send mypassword\r}
expect \n
log_user 1
expect eof
```

Direct the stdout of the above into a file and it should get just the contents of the `ls` file. Note how `log_user 0` is used to suppress output until we have read past the `\n` newline. Also, I had to add a `sleep` after the cat otherwise the tty was closed before all the data was read and the file ended up a little shorter than the original. There should probably be a better way of doing that.

Comment: i'd not recommend this. it also depends on the locale settings. basically it's not a good idea to use a pty to pass arbitrary binary data.

Comment: Actually, I've tried `set stty_init raw` and it doesn't work either (